# HTML Overflow print issues

Tags: html, css, overflow

So my problem is pretty simple. I am creating a report that can be anywhere from one to 100 pages roughly. it is variable based on multiple factors. What I am having issues with is that I need to have a set footer on EVERY page. I can get the footer to sit where I need it to and look the way I want. HOWEVER, the div's I am using to display my content overflow behind my footer. So my question is simply how to I for any content that does not fit in the content div to overflow on the next page and not simply to fill the printable space? is this even possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 0px;
        height: 278mm;
        margin-bottom: 20mm;
    }

    .page {
        width: 217mm;
        height: 268mm;
    }

    footer {
        bottom: 0;
        height: 10mm;
        background: black;
        color: white;
        width: 200mm;
        position: fixed;
    }

    .whiteBox {
        min-height: 5mm;
        height: auto;
        font-size: 3mm;
        line-height: 2;
        border-left: 1px solid #a95346;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #a95346;
        color: #000;
        letter-spacing: 0.1mm;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
      }

    .content {
        width: 217mm;
        height: 250mm;
        font-family: 'Verdana';
        display: inline-block;
        background: #fff;
        float: left;
    }

    .pb {
        page-break-before: always;
    }

    @media print {
        body {
          background-color: #fff;
          margin: 0px;
          height: 278mm;
          margin-bottom: 20mm;
        }

        .page {
          width: 217mm;
          height: 268mm;
        }

        footer {
          bottom: 0;
          height: 10mm;
          background: black;
          color: white;
          width: 200mm;
          position: fixed;
        }

        .whiteBox {
          min-height: 5mm;
          height: auto;
          font-size: 3mm;
          line-height: 2;
          border-left: 1px solid #a95346;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #a95346;
          color: #000;
          letter-spacing: 0.1mm;
          float: left;
          display: inline-block;
          text-align: center;
        }

        .content {
          width: 217mm;
          height: 250mm;
          font-family: 'Verdana';
          display: inline-block;
          background: #fff;
          float: left;
        }

        .pb {
          page-break-before: always;
        }
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page" style="border: 1px dotted;">
            <div class="content" style="border: none">
                <div class="whiteBox"   style="width: 217mm; border: none;">
                    <div class="whiteBox" style="width: 217mm; border: none">Text ...</div>
                    <div class="whiteBox" style="width: 217mm; border: none">Text ...</div>
                    <div class="whiteBox" style="width: 217mm; border: none">Text ...</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pb"></div>
            <div class="whiteBox" style="width: 217mm; border: none;">
                <footer>
                  <p>Posted by: Hege Refsnes</p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could it be that your floating the whitebox divs when printing too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886237/css-page-break-after-and-float-not-playing-nicely

Comment: Part of the problem I just discovered is that my @media print is useless. It isnt currently making any changes to how the code is displayed when printed. So to me because of this the float isn't currently an issue.

Comment: I did get the @media print to work...I had to add !important to each line to force it to be used instead of the standard html formatting.